# проблем запуска экранной клавиатуры в python

Tags: python

```
import os
os.startfile(r'C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_kay_bord.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.startfile(r'C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe'
```

Питаюсь подключить экранную клавиатуру из python, другие файлы открываются. Перестало работать после переустановки винды. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что файла нет. Вам там даже по-русски написано.

Comment: если бы его там не было, я бы вопрос не задавал, а так он на месте

Comment: Об этом надо было написать в вопросе. Мы тут не экстрасенсы.